# How do i get sub string using PHP code

Tags: php, regex, arrays, function, preg-match

```
./gallery/Chrysler/ch3.JPG
```

How can i get 'Chrysler'???

I have tried

```
$str =   "./gallery/Chrysler/ch3.JPG";

$matches = array();
$preg_match('/\[(.?)\]/',$str, $matches);
```

Please help me

Thanks,

Comment: Why do you need regex?

Answer (score 5):

Do like this. Make use of [`explode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) in PHP

```
$str = "./gallery/Chrysler/ch3.JPG";
$str=explode("/",$str);
echo $str[2]; // "prints" Chrysler
```

Answer (score 1):

If the string format doesn't change, then this can be done using [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode):

```
echo explode("/", $str)[2]; // => Chrysler
```

If the format changes, you can use a regular expression:

```
$str =   "./gallery/Chrysler/ch3.JPG";

$matches = array();
if(preg_match('#\./\w+/(\w+)/\w+\.\w+#',$str, $matches)) {
    echo $matches[1];
}
```

Output:

```
Chrysler
```

Answer (score 0):

Proper tools maybe?

```
$result = basename(dirname($str));
```

Answer (score 0):

Shankar Damodaran answer is correct.

To generalize, he could also use

```
$str = "./gallery/Chrysler/ch3.JPG";
$str = explode("/", $str);
echo $str[count($str) - 2]; // "prints" Chrysler
```

which works also for different use cases, for example:

```
$str = "/home/me/gallery/Chrysler/ch3.JPG";
```

if he wants to print the last directory in string, and not the second directory (it is unclear in the question...).